# Can a character using a polymorph spell be targeted by Enlarge Person?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, druid, wild-shape, polymorph

After looking over Shifter for a build, I noticed that they use the same class feature (Wild Shape) as a Druid. Wild Shape depends on Beast Shape (among other similar spells), which is a spell of the Polymorph subschool. After looking to see what polymorph spells do ([link](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph)), nothing says that you change your creature type, so even if your body is physically a bear, according to magic you're still a humanoid.

[Enlarge Person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/) can target any humanoid. Since a Druid or Shifter in Wild Shape still counts as a humanoid (according to magic), can a Wizard/Sorcerer cast Enlarge Person on the large bear, make them a huge bear, and grant the benefits of Enlarge Person? I can think of a few ways for Wizards and Sorcerers to potentially cast Enlarge Person after Beast Shape (or another polymorph spell) on themselves, but this seems like the most common potential scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, they can

However, the targeted creature **wont gain the benefits of enlarge person**, a size-changing effect, while under the effects of a polymorph effect. But if your polymorph duration expires before enlarge person does, you will still benefit from enlarge person.

From polymorph school:

> In addition, other spells that change your size have no effect on you while you are under the effects of a polymorph spell.

"Have no effect" does not mean you become an invalid target or that the spell is cancelled. It simply won't affect your character while the condition is true.

This may also be seen on [Stacking Effects](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#Stacking_Effects):

> *One Effect Makes Another Irrelevant*
>
> Sometimes, one spell can render a later spell irrelevant. **Both spells are still active**, but one has rendered the other useless in some fashion.

Comment: Where can I find that *a spell has no effect* means that *a spell has no effect while the subject remains an invalid target yet the spell's duration continues and resumes if the subject later becomes a valid target*? (My gut wants to say that *the spell has no effect* is the same as saying that *the spell fails*, but my gut has failed me before!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan the target was never invalid in the first place.

Comment: The same is true if you have permanent (as spell) Enlarge Person cast on you, then you polymorph into something else. It isnt dispelled due to that polymorph effect, it simply has "no effect on you while you are under the effects of a polymorph spell".